# My strings.Replace function is not working as i expected it to. ( C# --> Visual Basic.NET)

Tags: c#

I am trying to create a Chat Program that filters out a certain keyword.

The core of my problem<sup>*</sup> is:

```
        string swearWord = "swear";
        string result = swearWord.Replace("swear", "****");
```

This results in `result` always "****" and not some original string with "dipshit" replaced with for stars.

Complete code and runnable sample - https://ideone.com/e.js/CD1zpr

```
public partial class MainWindow: Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string chatnaam = txtNaam.Text;
        string chatbericht = txtBericht.Text;
        txtblock1.Inlines.Add(new Bold(new Run(chatnaam )));
        txtblock1.Inlines.Add(" says: ");
        txtblock1.Inlines.Add(Environment.NewLine);
        txtblock1.Inlines.Add(Environment.NewLine);
        txtblock1.Inlines.Add(chatbericht);
        txtblock1.Inlines.Add(Environment.NewLine);
        txtblock1.Inlines.Add(Environment.NewLine);
        string Dipshit = "Dipshit";
        txtblock1.Text = Dipshit.Replace("Dipshit", "****");

    }
```

It filters out any keyword for some reason.
I only want it to replace the word "Dipshit".

Here is an image demonstrating what I mean: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y0RQI.jpg

---

<sub><sup>*</sup>While this is very confusing example it show why creating minimal example is useful...</sub>

Comment: What is the result of this code, and how does it differ from what you expect?

Comment: I immediately get the "****" when i type in any kind of text .

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/AB5959K Here is an image showing my results.

Comment: You are calling `Replace` on a string that has nothing to do with your inputs

Comment: oke, I tried using txtBox, where I actually type in my message. But then I get the "***" in the txtBox instead. How should i properly formulate this? Thanks in Advance

Comment: `txtblock1.Text = chatnaam.Replace("Dipshit", "****");`? I don't know what you tried, but that would be my guess for what you are trying to do

Comment: This line is the culprit: `txtblock1.Text = Dipshit.Replace("Dipshit", "****");` You are replacing the s** and putting it in text block overwriting everything there.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing now is setting the Text box `txtblock1` to ***** . Because `Disphit.Replace` returns a string which it 'sends' to the textbox. So regardless what you type, that textblock will be set to ****

I assume you want to change the `chatbericht` to ***** if it includes the word 'dipshit'. In which case you should check if it does, and if so. You replace it.

Like so for example:

```
        string chatnaam = txtNaam.Text;
        string chatbericht = txtBericht.Text;
        txtblock1.Inlines.Add(new Bold(new Run(chatnaam )));
        txtblock1.Inlines.Add(" says: ");
        txtblock1.Inlines.Add(Environment.NewLine);
        txtblock1.Inlines.Add(Environment.NewLine);
        chatbericht = chatbericht.Replace("Dipshit", "****"); // the change
        txtblock1.Inlines.Add(chatbericht);
        txtblock1.Inlines.Add(Environment.NewLine);
        txtblock1.Inlines.Add(Environment.NewLine);
```

Of course, this example is case sensitive, for insensitive replacement, you'll have to do some regex or overload the replace method to take a stringcomparision.

**And for your future questions**, please use **English** variable names. It's hard to understand what the Dutch(?) words mean/contextualize, any foreign language for that matter.